# MATLAB 'cat()' function returning different matrix size

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cat

If I perform `s.device_macs` then I get back a `<1x3503 cell>` so I would expect this as the output of my concatenate but I have 2 things I'm unsure on when I use: `a = cat(2,s.device_macs)`

To concatenate previously I used `cat(1,x)` but this doesn't work however the number `2` lets it run and the second thing is that it returns a <1x603326 cell>, obviously much larger than when I don't try and use `cat()`.

Thanks alot, from a MATLAB newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a cheating method of solving this. As I mentioned the `ans` was coming out correct and so I decided to just use this:

```
s.device_macs; % This gives the answer of <1x3503 cell>
macId = ans; % I now make macId copy answer
clear ans; % Now I wipe ans leaving me with just macId
```

I know this isn't an efficient method of coding compared to just knowing the language but duct-tape-esque fixes are fun to find :P.

Comment: Try `macId = { s.device_macs };` ?

Comment: What do these do or how do I find some help text on this just so I know why it's giving me the answer it is doing?

Comment: My data has 106 different people in it and I think I get it, that using the `{}` curly braces creates a matrix, with seperate entries for each of the people because I can do `s(x).device_macs` where x is in 1:106

And in this case `macId = { s.device_macs };` returns it as a <1x106 cell>. Does this sound half correct?

Cheers!

Comment: `{}` doesn't create a matrix, it creates a cell array.  `[]` creates a matrix.  The main difference is that a matrix has to be square and have uniform type, while a cell array can be jagged and contain different types.

Answer (score 0):

`s.device_macs` is a 1 row (first dimension) x 3503 column (second dimension) vector. That is why you have to specify 2 in `cat(2,s.device_macs)`, so that it concatenates along the second dimension -- the columns. My guess is that the 1x603326 result is a string with 603326 characters (in columns), but not entirely sure... hopefully someone else can help here.